# How to show Notification in Swift more than once?

Tags: swift, notifications

Is there anyway to show the notification with swift every 15 seconds ? I checked that via

```
notification.fireDate=NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15)
```

but it doesn't work everytime it just showed once , how we can do it as a loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't schedule a notification every 15 second. The minimum time between notifications it is 1 minute which it is also very unlikely needed.

> var repeatInterval: NSCalendarUnit { get set }
>
> Description    The calendar interval at which to reschedule the
>   notification. If you assign a calendar unit such as weekly
>   (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system
>   reschedules the notification for delivery at the specified interval.
>   Note that intervals of less than one minute are not supported. The
>   default value is 0, which means that the system fires the notification
>   once and then discards it.

So just set it up as follow:

```
notification.repeatInterval = .Minute
```

Comment: Thnx Leo it was interesting ! 1++

Answer (score 0):

You can set `localNotification.repeatInterval` property which as to be of type  `NSCalendarUnit`